# Are views and answer scores considered in the question ban algorithm?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Is a question with a lot of views but 0 score or [-5;-1] score and highly voted answers treated any different from other questions in the same score range ?

High views and neutral/slightly negative views and high voted answers would suggest that the question was of interest to site viewers and generated value. Is this in any way considered in the algorithm or is "value for the site" simply based on question votes?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I don't think answer scores should be taken in to consideration. There are plenty of terrible questions with good answers.

Comment: And either way, it isn't that "value for the site" is based solely on questions but that "value of questions" is based solely on questions.

Comment: The algorithm is deliberately kept secret so that people can't game the system.

Comment: views are no indication the question or answer is good or bad.  If the right person, tweets a question out, a bad question can get way to much attention then its worth.